# What does "n_features" and "centers" parameters mean in make_blobs in SciKit?

Tags: scikit-learn

I have gone through the documents about `n_features` and `centers` parameters in `make_blobs` function in `SciKit`. However, every explanation I've seen doesn't sound so clear to me since I am new to `SciKit` and Mathematics. I am wondering what do these two parameters: `n_features`, `centers` do in `make_blobs` function as below.

```
make_blobs(n_samples=50, n_features=2, centers=2, random_state=75)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you understand about `make_blobs` so far?

Comment: Edit: As far as I know, I only know that make_blobs function literally makes blobs and that through a few samples I assign, it gives me a tuple consists of two elements which are samples. I know that features give me another column of samples but I don't know what it means to have another column. What's more, I have no idea what the center means.

Comment: Plus, I am confused about the second element of the tuple. What does it mean exactly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `make_blobs` function is a part of `sklearn.datasets.samples_generator`. All methods in the package, help us to generate data samples or datasets. In machine learning, which scikit-learn all about, datasets are used to evaluate performance of machine learning models. This is an example on how to evaluate a [KNN classifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html):

```
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

X, y = make_blobs(n_features=2, centers=3)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
model = KNeighborsClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
acc = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred) * 100
print('accuracy: {}%'.format(acc))
```

Now, as you mentioned, `n_features` determined how many columns or features the generated datasets will have. In machine learning, features correspond to numerical characteristics data. For example, in [Iris Dataset](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/datasets/plot_iris_dataset.html), there are 4 features (Sepal Length, Sepal Width, Petal Length and Petal Width) so there are 4 numerical columns in the dataset. So by increasing `n_features` in `make_blobs`, we are adding more features hence increase the complexity of generated dataset.

As for the `centers`, it is easier to understand by visualizing the generated dataset. I use `matplotlib` to help us on that:

```
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
import matplot

# plot 1
X, y = make_blobs(n_features=2, centers=1)
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y)
plt.savefig('centers_1.png')
plt.title('centers = 1')

# plot 2    
X, y = make_blobs(n_features=2, centers=2)
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y)
plt.title('centers = 2')

# plot 3
X, y = make_blobs(n_features=2, centers=3)
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y)
plt.title('centers = 3')

plt.show()
```

[image: centers=1]

[image: centers=2]

[image: centers=3]

If you run the code above you can easily see that `centers` corresponds to number of classes generated in the data. It uses centers as a term because samples that belong to same class, tend to gather close to a center (coordinate).

Comment: I think this helped a lot! Thank you!

Comment: The visualization clicked for me, thank you so much!